# npm run build doesn't work - gulp-sourcemaps error

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I do `npm install`, I ran `npm run build` after and I got this error:

D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika>npm run build

> ets-log210-typescript-node-api@2.0.0 build
> gulp build

> Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sourcemaps'
>
> Require stack:
>
> - D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\gulpfile.js
> - D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js
> - D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned^4.0.0\index.js
> - D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js
> - D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
> at Object. (D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\gulpfile.js:4:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: [
> 'D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\gulpfile.js',
> 'D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js',
> 'D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js',
> 'D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js',
> 'D:\Data\s20213-log210-03-lab0-ayoubmoudrika\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'
> ]
> }

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ww30.png)

Comment: try deleting the node modules folder and npm install again

Comment: I tried that many times..

Comment: Do you have a dependency for gulp-sourcmaps in your package json?

Comment: yup that was the prob thanks